# Copy the google plus floating toolbar menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I'm trying to emulate a "toolbar" type floating menu used by the android google plus app. The menu appears when you scroll up the page and hides nicely when you scroll down.

I'm guessing this is a linear layout with some sort of animation. Is that correct? Any ideas on how to reproduce?

[image: Google Plus menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this effect is to call animate().translationY(value) on the object you want to slide down/up.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at Roman Nurik's scroll tricks example [here](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks). It shows how to have a quick return view like the one you mention.

Comment: and Roman's corresponding [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113735310430199015092/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) with description and video.